# How to make a one column as read only in JS grid based on the conditions

Tags: sharepoint

I have a JS grid. I need to make few columns read only based on the run time value of another column.

For e.g. my Grid has 2 columns : Marks and Eligible

If I select Name from the dropdown(separate drop down on the page) and marks are < 50 , eligible column should be read-only for that name.

Thanks,

Sandy

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSOM (JavaScript Object Model) and the JSlink of your forms Properies. With this you could attach a JS file, and it will be launch at the redering. After you have just to code your logic (attach event on change of your dropDown, if value < 50 .... )

Comment: Can you provide more details . My grids are in acsx page

Comment: If your grid is in a ascx, (a custom User Control) ou could use simple Javascript you don't have to use JSLink. You put you scrip/link file, in your ascx file. Use the power of JavaScript to do you custom logic validation/rendering only in client side

Comment: your problem is not concerning sharepoint. It concerning JSGrid. I don't know JSGrid framwor. But with a littel search i found this : [JSGrid Demo](http://js-grid.com/demos/), check the Custom Grid Field. Create your custom field rendering (insertTemplate, editTemplate...) use custom logic to check your value to return input, label or input disable ....